# Is there a way to let PostgreSQL restore but not create a new timeline

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 and am creating a standby server. Since PostgreSQL 8.4 doesn't have built-in replication support, I did the following things try to get read only access to the standby server, and not to transfar full backup everyday.

- Set master to transfer WAL files to the standby server in `postgresql.conf`

  ```
  archive_mode = on  
  archive_command = 'scp -C %p standby:/var/lib/pgsql/backups/%f'
  ```
- create a `recovery.conf` on the standby server

  ```
  restore_command = 'mv /var/lib/pgsql/backups/%f %p'
  recovery_end_command = 'mv /var/lib/pgsql/data/recovery.{done,conf}'
  ```
- `pg_ctl restart -m fast` once a day

Then I realized that PostgreSQL did restore the transfered WAL files at the initial start up, but does not after a restart. I found the next message in the log file.

> LOG: selected new timeline ID: 2

It seems that standby server is already on a new timeline, but master server is still sending old timeline's WAL file, which makes standby server not restoring.

So is there a way to make it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: sDid you promote the standby at some point? It can't replay the \

Comment: It reads like you'd want to continue restoring into a secondary server that at some point has become a live server? That's not possible because as soon as the end of the recovery, it is allowed to diverge irrevocably from the primary. The new timeline is just a sign indicating that.